# Git: can't undo local changes (error: path ... is unmerged)

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

I have following working tree state

```
$ git status foo/bar.txt
# On branch master
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       deleted by us:      foo/bar.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

File `foo/bar.txt` is there and I want to get it to the "unchanged state" again (similar to 'svn revert'):

```
$ git checkout HEAD foo/bar.txt
error: path 'foo/bar.txt' is unmerged
$ git reset HEAD foo/bar.txt
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       foo/bar.txt
```

Now it is getting confusing:

```
$ git status foo/bar.txt
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   foo/bar.txt
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   foo/bar.txt
#
```

The same file in both sections, new *and* modified? What should I do?

Comment: I wish someone could explain how do we get into this situation, *why* it happens, and why the solution works.

Comment: I got into this situation when I popped my stash after a rebase which got me into a merge conflict (stash pop does a merge)....To resolve it, i did a "checkout --theirs" ....apparently my changes were still there....to remove those..I tried a checkout on the file again..that's when I saw the above error.

Comment: I got into this situation after switch to main branch, git pull and do a git stash pop.

Answer (score 750, accepted):

You did it the wrong way around. You are meant to reset first to unstage the file, then checkout to revert local changes.

Try this:

```
$ git reset foo/bar.txt
$ git checkout foo/bar.txt
```

Comment: Thanks; worked like a charm!  I had to commit (_not_ with the -a arg, the relevant changes were already staged) and then I was able to push/pull like normal.

Comment: For me it required a: <br/>                                             $ git reset -- foo/bar.txt <br/> $ git checkout -- foo/bar.txt <br/> (Notice the extra "--" in between)

Comment: For me, git reset resets *all* files, not just the listed one.. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The good syntax is "git reset HEAD file1 file2 ..." then "git checkout -- file1 file2..."

Comment: It's always amusing when the highest voted answer basically just says "you're doing it wrong" :)

Comment: An explanation (on what things do) would have been great …

Comment: modern way using `git restore` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021161/git-cant-undo-local-changes-error-path-is-unmerged/73707347#73707347

Answer (score 86):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
$ git reset -- foo/bar.txt
$ git checkout foo/bar.txt
```

Answer (score 17):

```
git checkout origin/[branch] .
git status
```

// Note dot (.) at the end. And all will be good

Answer (score 10):

If the above answers didn't work try:

```
git reset --merge
```

Answer (score 7):

In recent git versions, `git restore` is supposed to be a "better" way to revert undesired local changes than the overloaded `checkout`.  Great, that sounds reasonable - a nice simple purpose-built tool for a common operation.

But, here's my new "favorite" git bug.  Yes, I know some git-head is going to say, "It's not a bug, it's by design".  But with this kind of user interface, I stand by the "bug" moniker:

```
% git restore LEGAL
error: path 'LEGAL' is unmerged
# okay, fine...
% git restore --ignore-unmerged LEGAL
warning: path 'LEGAL' is unmerged
# Arg, what?!
```

(brought to you by git 2.25.1)

First the minor issue: when a tool refuses to do something because of a particular condition, it's not just a warning.  At *least* it should say the operation was not performed.  Now I have to go investigate whether the operation was actually performed or not (hint: it wasn't).

The second issue, of course, is obvious.  Now, let's look at the man page entry to see why this fantastic tool won't do what I am telling it to do:

```
   --ignore-unmerged
       When restoring files on the working tree from the index, do not
       abort the operation if there are unmerged entries and neither
       --ours, --theirs, --merge or --conflict is specified. Unmerged
       paths on the working tree are left alone.
```

Holy smokes!  I guess the git-ish fix for the user interface problem here will be to rename the option from `--ignore-unmerged` to `--ignore-unmerged-except-in-cases-where-we-do-not-want-to-allow-that--consult-documentation-then-source-code-then-team-of-gurus-when-you-cannot-figure-it-out---and-wait-while-half-of-them-argue-about-why-it-is-right-as-is-while-the-other-half-advocate-adding-four-more-options-as-the-fix`.

Then go to the community to find out a fix.  I dare you.

Obviously, I didn't have my refs in a state where the tree-ish blobs could be resolved with the commit-ishes from working file to staging area... err index?

Comment: Here's the way to fix it with `git restore` (although I agree with you it's not intuitive): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021161/git-cant-undo-local-changes-error-path-is-unmerged/73707347#73707347

Comment: @wisbucky... Thanks.  If I ever run into that problem again, I'll try that.  My fix was to convert the repo to mercurial and use that instead. The friction is far less.

Comment: I was hitting this issue on a cherry-pick, and @wisbucky's solution didn't cut it. Using `--ours` did what I was after, just discarding the incoming cherry picked file. @Juan you're totally right about those warning messages needing to say what they did't do, not just why they didn't do it. And a bit more explanation that the ambiguity from the conflict needs to be resolved (by using `--ours`, etc) would be super helpful to this error message.

Answer (score 1):

The "modern" way to fix the unmerged path error, which can happen when you pop your stash, using the `restore` command (since git v2.23, Aug 2019):

```bash
# unstage the file
git restore --staged myfile

# restore the file (lose your working dir changes)
git restore myfile
```

Answer (score -3):

```
git checkout foo/bar.txt
```

did you tried that? (without a HEAD keyword)

I usually revert my changes this way.

Comment: Typical error when trying a `checkout` in the midst of a merge:  
`$ git co path/to/file` =result=> 
`error: path 'path/to/file' is unmerged`
 => so, first run: `$ git reset path/to/file`, and then the `git checkout path/to/file` should work.

Comment: Not specifying HEAD will make git checkout check out from the index, which is a weaker operation (the content source is the index rather than HEAD). Furthermore I don’t think that makes a difference in this case at all - with the specific problem the question stated. Did *you* try that?

Answer (score -4):

I find [git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) very useful for temporal handling of all 'dirty' states.

Comment: If you find it useful, please give an explanation on how it would help in this concrete case. How would you use it here?