# Git says a file is unmerged and I can't commit, but the file seems to be merged

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I had about 12 file conflicts when I merged branches. I manually fixed all the conflicts and staged the files. But now when I try to commit, it says one of the files is unmerged.

```
U      app/models/disclosure_event.rb
fatal: 'commit' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

When I type `git status`, it shows all the changed files, including "disclosure_event.rb", under `Changes to be committed`. It shows no files as unstaged. I've repeatedly tried to add the file, but it seems to do nothing. If I open the file, everything looks great.

Any ideas? I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Sounds like yet another Git bug.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: can't undo local changes (error: path ... is unmerged)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021161/git-cant-undo-local-changes-error-path-is-unmerged)

Answer (score 72):

I can't tell you what's wrong, but you might try

```
git reset app/models/disclosure_even.rb
git add app/models/disclosure_even.rb
```

and then commit.

Comment: I had to use "git reset -- lib/OaisAip.php", but that got me going!

Comment: I had to specify `git reset HEAD app/models/disclosure_even.rb`. Otherwise, I'd get `git reset app/models/disclosure_even.rb =>
fatal: ambiguous argument 'app/models/disclosure_even.rb': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions`

Answer (score 14):

I had exactly the same situation today on branches merging (not rebasing).

I spot, that file it errors on, in your case:

```
U      app/models/disclosure_event.rb
```

was absent in git status. But is could be seen as unmerged in gitk GUI. It also was absent in working copy (moved to another place in my case).

I tried `git rm`, and it solved the problem:

```
git rm app/models/disclosure_event.rb
```

Comment: Didn't work here... `git rm backend/server/main.js => 
backend/server/main.js: needs merge`

Answer (score 8):

Set the remote is `origin` and the branch is `master`, and say you already have `master` checked out, might try the following:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

It will set the current branch and points it to the HEAD of the remote branch.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered such situation before with rebase. Git determines that you leave some files as they were before merge and thinks you still didn't merge them. That time I googled and find out many suggestions to do just `git rebase --skip`. It worked for me.

More detailed description of such case: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/BUG-git-rebase-is-confuse-if-conflict-resolution-doesn-t-produce-diff-td726597.html

Similar problem: [Git rebase: conflicts keep blocking progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033009/git-rebase-conflicts-keep-blocking-progress)

I'm not sure it is your case if you have merge, though.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the 2 suggestions without any luck. And I couldn't get it to reset back to HEAD, so I just re-cloned the repository and did the entire merge over and didn't have any issues. For what it's worth, I now highly recommend p4merge over vimdiff...

Comment: I also recommend `mcdiff` (from the `mc` package) instead of the terrible vimdiff.