# Cannot checkout, file is unmerged

Tags: git, version-control, merge-conflict-resolution

I am trying to remove the file from my working directory but after using the following command

```
git checkout file_Name.txt
```

I got the following error message

```
error: path 'first_Name.txt' is unmerged
```

What is that and how to resolve it?

Following is my git status

```
$ git status
On branch master
You are currently reverting commit f200bf5.
  (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:      first_file.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        explore_california/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: That moved to the staging index but i am not able to clean the folder explore_california/

Comment: If you want to delete `explore_california` then just do a `rm -r explore_california` since it is not being tracked by git.

Comment: What that did is asking me to remove more than 50 files individually and i m still pressing y?

Comment: But It worked Finally.Thanx

Comment: @brokenfoot add it as an answer.

Comment: @khan: See this link on why it asks for your permission to delete files: http://superuser.com/questions/345923/remove-file-without-asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: can't undo local changes (error: path ... is unmerged)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021161/git-cant-undo-local-changes-error-path-is-unmerged)

Comment: The reason is somehow you moved this file to staging (like running `git add first_Name.txt`) it needs to be unstaged before checked out. 

So easily run `git reset first_Name.txt` then you run `git checkout first_Name.txt`

Expect the changes are reverted.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To remove tracked files (first_file.txt) from git:

```
git rm first_file.txt
```

And to remove untracked files, use:

```
rm -r explore_california
```

Answer (score 212):

If you want to discard modifications you made to the file, you can do:

```
git reset first_Name.txt
git checkout first_Name.txt
```

Comment: Needs the double hyphen arg?  git reset -- first_name.txt and git checkout -- first_name.txt

Comment: You only use the `--` to separate the tree you want to check out from the files you want to check out. To a more in depth explanation, take a loot here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321458/meaning-of-git-checkout-double-dashes

Comment: I think it's safer to use the double-hyphen `git reset -- first_Name.txt` and `git checkout -- first_Name.txt` just in case the filename is the same as one of your branches/tags/commits.

Answer (score 32):

Following worked for me

```
git reset HEAD
```

I was getting the bellow error

```
git stash
src/config.php: needs merge
src/config.php: needs merge
src/config.php: unmerge(230a02b5bf1c6eab8adce2cec8d573822d21241d)
src/config.php: unmerged (f5cc88c0fda69bf72107bcc5c2860c3e5eb978fa)
```

Then i ran

```
git reset HEAD
```

it worked

Answer (score 21):

status tell you what to do.

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
```

you probably applied a stash or something else that cause a conflict.

either add, reset, or rm.

Comment: Exactly I applied a stash. Now the question is when to use `add`, when `reset` and when do I use `rm`? For example, I don't want to keep the stashed version but the version from upstream instead?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think execute

```
 git rm first_file.txt
```

is a good idea.

1. when git notice your files is unmerged, you should ensure you had committed it.
2. And then open the conflict file:

   `cat first_file.txt`
3. fix the conflict

4.

`git add file`

```
git commit -m "fix conflict"
```

5.
    `git push`

it should works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

```
git stash -u
```

Step 2:

```
git stash drop stash@{1}
```

Step 3:

```
git checkout .
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that I need the -f option. Such as the following:

```
git rm -f first_file.txt
```

to get rid of the "needs merge" error.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved by doing below 2 easy steps :

step 1: git reset Head
step 2: git add .

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

It will recover file from curreny HEAD

```
    git restore -S -W file_Name.txt
```