# How to override unmerged git checkout with upstream version

Tags: git, merge, git-checkout

I’m attempting to revert a file modified locally to the version that is most recent upstream, effectively undoing my changes.

```
$ git checkout --  Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist
error: path ‘Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist' is unmerged
```

Using -f alters the error to warn, but still won’t make the change (???)

```
$ git checkout  -f -- Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist
warning: path ‘Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist' is unmerged
```

The file itself looks like this:

```
$ git diff Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist
diff --cc Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist
index 6c576d9,0209baa..0000000
--- a/Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist
+++ b/Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist
@@@ -50,7 -50,7 +50,11 @@@
                </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
++<<<<<<< Updated upstream
 +      <string>5922</string>
++=======
+       <string>5918</string>
++>>>>>>> Stashed changes
        <key>Fabric</key>
        <dict>
                <key>APIKey</key>
```

How do I override the local files and apply upstream changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: can't undo local changes (error: path ... is unmerged)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021161/git-cant-undo-local-changes-error-path-is-unmerged)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You might need to reset the file first, before doing the checkout:

```
git reset -- Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist
git checkout -- Jovie/Jovie-Info.plist
```

The reset un-stage the changes in progress (here the merge, with the conflict markers in the file).
Then the checkout can restore the index with the last commit content.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to do for all ***both modified*** unmerged files , there is a simple way to do that instead of doing for each one:

```
git reset $( git status | grep both | awk '{print $4}')
git checkout $( git status | grep modified | awk '{print $3}')
```

If you need to do for all ***[added/deleted] by us*** unmerged files , there is a simple way to do that instead of doing for each one:

```
git reset $( git status | grep us | awk '{print $5}')
git checkout $( git status | grep modified | awk '{print $3}')
```

If you need to do for all ***[added/deleted] by them*** unmerged files , there is a simple way to do that instead of doing for each one:

```
git reset $( git status | grep them | awk '{print $5}')
git checkout $( git status | grep modified | awk '{print $3}')
```